# Performance of Azure SDK v12 vs Storage Data Movement Library?

Tags: azure, azure-storage, azure-blob-storage, azure-sdk-.net

I know that the Storage Data Movement Library is supposed to be faster when uploading and downloading files to and from blob storage, but I am not seeing the performance benefits of it when compared to Azure SDK v12. I got an average of 37.463 seconds with Azure SDK v12 and 41.863 seconds using Storage Data Movement Library (SDML).

Here is the code using SDML:

```
namespace FunctionApp
{
    using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
    using Microsoft.Azure.Storage;
    using Microsoft.Azure.Storage.Blob;
    using Microsoft.Azure.Storage.DataMovement;
    using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs;
    using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.Http;
    using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;

    using System;
    using System.Diagnostics;
    using System.IO;
    using System.IO.Compression;
    using System.Net;
    using System.Net.Http;
    using System.Threading;
    using System.Threading.Tasks;
    using System.Web.Http;

    public static class Function1
    {
        [FunctionName("A")]
        public static async Task<IActionResult> HttpStart(
            [HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Anonymous, "post", Route = "testRoute")] HttpRequestMessage req,
            ILogger log)
        {
            Stopwatch timer = new Stopwatch();
            timer.Start();
            try
            {
                ServicePointManager.Expect100Continue = false;
                ServicePointManager.DefaultConnectionLimit = Environment.ProcessorCount * 8;
                TransferManager.Configurations.ParallelOperations = 64;

                string fileToDownload = "<URI to zip file in blob storage containing two 300MB files";
                string connectionString = "<connection string to storage account>";
                string containerName = "<container to upload files to>";

                using MemoryStream test = new MemoryStream();
                CloudBlockBlob sourceBlob = new CloudBlockBlob(new Uri(fileToDownload));
                await TransferManager.DownloadAsync(sourceBlob, test);

                CloudStorageAccount account = CloudStorageAccount.Parse(connectionString);
                CloudBlobClient blobClient = account.CreateCloudBlobClient();
                CloudBlobContainer container = blobClient.GetContainerReference(containerName);

                using ZipArchive zipArchive = new ZipArchive(test);
                foreach (ZipArchiveEntry file in zipArchive.Entries)
                {
                    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(file.Name))
                    {
                        CloudBlockBlob destBlob = container.GetBlockBlobReference(file.FullName);
                        using Stream stream = file.Open();
                        await TransferManager.UploadAsync(stream, destBlob);
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception exception)
            {
                return new InternalServerErrorResult();
            }

            timer.Stop();
            return new OkObjectResult(timer.ElapsedMilliseconds);
        }
    }
}
```

Here is the code using Azure SDK v12:

```
namespace FunctionApp
{
    using Azure.Storage.Blobs;
    using Azure.Storage.Blobs.Specialized;

    using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
    using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs;
    using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.Http;
    using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;

    using System;
    using System.Diagnostics;
    using System.IO;
    using System.IO.Compression;
    using System.Net;
    using System.Net.Http;
    using System.Threading;
    using System.Threading.Tasks;
    using System.Web.Http;

    public static class Function1
    {
        [FunctionName("A")]
        public static async Task<IActionResult> HttpStart(
            [HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Anonymous, "post", Route = "testRoute")] HttpRequestMessage req,
            ILogger log)
        {
            Stopwatch timer = new Stopwatch();
            timer.Start();
            try
            {
                ServicePointManager.Expect100Continue = false;
                ServicePointManager.DefaultConnectionLimit = Environment.ProcessorCount * 8;

                string fileToDownload = "<URI to zip file in blob storage containing two 300MB files";
                string connectionString = "<connection string to storage account>";
                string containerName = "<container to upload files to>";

                using MemoryStream test = new MemoryStream();
                BlockBlobClient client = new BlockBlobClient(new Uri(fileToDownload));

                await client.DownloadToAsync(test);
                BlobContainerClient containerClient = new BlobContainerClient(connectionString, containerName);

                using ZipArchive zipArchive = new ZipArchive(test);
                foreach (ZipArchiveEntry file in zipArchive.Entries)
                {
                    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(file.Name))
                    {
                        BlockBlobClient blockBlobClient = containerClient.GetBlockBlobClient(file.FullName);
                        using Stream stream = file.Open();
                        await blockBlobClient.UploadAsync(stream);
                    }
                }

            }
            catch (Exception exception)
            {
                return new InternalServerErrorResult();
            }

            timer.Stop();
            return new OkObjectResult(timer.ElapsedMilliseconds) ;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For Data Movement library, you may set `ParallelOperations` and `BlockSize`, like below:

```
TransferManager.Configurations.ParallelOperations = 20;
TransferManager.Configurations.BlockSize = 20971520*2; //20M
```

I did the test at my side, SDML is more faster.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions! I realized the limiting factor was obviously my own internet now. Either my internet didn't have enough bandwidth to support the number of parallel operations of SDML or my speed was too slow. Today my internet was upgraded, and rerunning the tests on your settings and the original settings, I get 12.3366 seconds and 12.060 seconds, respectively. With Azure SDK v12, I am getting 19.9022 seconds. These tests were run on two 500MB files.