# Xamarin Forms : How to track file uploading with a progress bar while using Azure.storage.blobs V12

Tags: c#, .net, azure, xamarin.forms, azure-blob-storage

I am working on Xamarin Forms apps and I am using the library [Azure.storage.blobs V12](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Azure.Storage.Blobs/) to upload data in my Datalake.

I have manage to upload a file in my Azure Storage datalake and it is working.

**What I would like :**

1. chunk upload to Azure
2. Track the upload with my progress bar

to do do a chunk upload to A

I have looked to many links but without success (see links below). Thanks for your help in advance.

In the file **AzureDataLakeManager.cs**, here is my uploading code :

```
static BlobContainerClient GetContainer(ContainerType containerType)
{
    BlobServiceClient blobServiceClient = new BlobServiceClient(StorageConnection);
    BlobContainerClient container = blobServiceClient.GetBlobContainerClient(containerType.ToString().ToLower());
    return container;
}



public static async Task<string> UploadFileAsync(ContainerType containerType, Stream stream, string folder, string userid)
    {
        try
        {

            var container = GetContainer(containerType);
            // await container.CreateIfNotExistsAsync();
            var name = folder + "/" + userid;
            var fileBlob = container.GetBlobClient(name);

            await fileBlob.UploadAsync(stream);



            return name;

        }

        catch (Exception e)
        {
            
            return null;
        }

    }
```

In the content Page where I would like to display the Uploading **MyStudio.Xalm**, here is my xalm with my progressBar :

```
<StackLayout>
 <ProgressBar  x:Name="progressBar" ></ProgressBar>
</StackLayout>
```

In the content Page c# code file  **MyStudio.Xalm.cs**, here  is the function that change My ProgressBar Status :

```
void CalculateProgress(long completed, long total)
{
    var comp = Convert.ToDouble(completed);
    var tot = Convert.ToDouble(total);
    var percentage = comp / tot;
    progressBar.ProgressTo(percentage,100,Easing.Linear);

}
```

Here is the link that I have found :

- [Upload or download file from Azure Blob Storage with progress
  percentage c#](https://www.craftedforeveryone.com/upload-or-download-file-from-azure-blob-storage-with-progress-percentage-csharp/)
- [Uploading Blobs with the V12 Storage SDK](https://markheath.net/post/upload-blobs-with-v12-sdk)
- [How to upload a large file in chunks with parallelism in Azure SDK
  v12?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61857337/how-to-upload-a-large-file-in-chunks-with-parallelism-in-azure-sdk-v12)
- [How to upload large files in chunks using rest API, azure blob list
  storage from salesforce using LWC.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/1194952/how-to-upload-large-files-in-chunks-using-rest-api)

Comment: What's the actual behavior? Is the value of percentage correct?

Comment: I do not know how to chunk data and load it to Azure. Once done,  I can count the number of chunk then send percentage to my progress bar function